# Tomcat Is not Starting after Github Actions pipeline

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, tomcat7, github-actions

I'm using a self-hosted GitHub Actions Runner to deploy a small Java application.

The runner is inside a Docker container, that I created using a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
LABEL Author="***"

ARG GH_ACTIONS_RUNNER_VERSION=2.290.1

RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y curl && \
    apt-get install -y git && \
    apt-get install -y sudo && \
    apt-get install -y net-tools && \
    apt-get install -y maven

# GITHUB ACTIONS RUNNER
RUN curl -o actions-runner-linux-x64.tar.gz -L "https://github.com/actions/runner/releases/download/v${GH_ACTIONS_RUNNER_VERSION}/actions-runner-linux-x64-${GH_ACTIONS_RUNNER_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
    && tar xzf ./actions-runner-linux-x64.tar.gz \
    && rm -f actions-runner-linux-x64.tar.gz

# TOMCAT
EXPOSE 8080
RUN cd tmp && \
    wget "http://apache.uvigo.es/tomcat/tomcat-9/v9.0.62/bin/apache-tomcat-9.0.62.tar.gz" && \
    tar -zxvf /tmp/apache-tomcat-9.0.62.tar.gz -C /usr/local && \
    cd /usr/local && mv apache-tomcat-9.0.62 tomcat && \
    cd /tmp && rm -rf *

# MYSQL
EXPOSE 3306
RUN sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y mysql-server

# PHANTOMJS
RUN cd tmp && \
    wget "https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2" && \
    tar xvjf /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
    mv /tmp/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin && \
    rm -rf *


CMD  sudo usermod -d /var/lib/mysql/ mysql && sudo service mysql start && sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start && /bin/bash
```

And I'm using the following main.yaml file to execute the pipelines:

```
name: CI

on:

  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
   
  pruebas-unitarias:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.3
      - name: Unit Tests
        run: mvn test

  empaquetar:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: pruebas-unitarias
    steps:
      - name: build
        run: mvn package -DskipTests=true
      - name: upload-artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: baloncesto
          path: target/

  pruebas-funcionales:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    needs: empaquetar
    steps:
      - run: cp -r target/Baloncesto /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
      - run: mysql -u root < db/baloncesto.sql
      - run: export DATABASE_HOST="jdbc:mysql://localhost"
      - run: export DATABASE_PORT="3306"
      - run: export DATABASE_NAME="baloncesto"
      - run: export DATABASE_USER="usuario"
      - run: export DATABASE_PASS="clave"
      - run: sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop
      - run: sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start
```

However, after the pipeline executes, it is supposed to run the tomcat server on port 8080,but it's not.

Inside the pipeline when I stop the tomcat server with "sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh stop" the ports look like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42844        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42882        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42804        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42814        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42822        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42858        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42852        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52434         127.0.0.1:8005          TIME_WAIT
```

And when I start it with "sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start" the ports looks like this:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42844        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42882        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42934        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42914        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42918        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42836        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42872        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 172.17.0.3:42840        13.107.42.16:443        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:52434         127.0.0.1:8005          TIME_WAIT
```

And then, on the container, after the pipeline is executed, the ports are like this:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 172.17.0.3:42322        13.107.42.16:443        ESTABLISHED
```

Only the Mysql server is running. I don't know what is happening...

Pd: The tomcat server was already started before the pipeline. We need to stop and start the server again in order to set the Database variables.

Comment: You might want to add steps in the last job to inspect the machine (ls -la some dirs and make sure the state is what you expect).  remember the workflow is also a good debugging tool.

Comment: also, is there just one runner?  each job can go to another runner.   so you're copying from target dir to webapps but what if target isn't there?  what it should probably be doing is downloading the artifact that was uploaded in the previous job not assuming it's on disk.

Comment: Hi bryanmac, thanks for respond. Yeah the copy from target to webapps is done. Actually when I run "$ sh /usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh start" in the container after the pipeline the application starts on port 8080 in my browser. But I lose all the database variables from the pipeline so, I cannot send data to the database.

Comment: Also each step in actions is isolated out of proc and run out of proc so the way you're doing an export per step might be problematic.  If it was me, I would put all those steps in one shell script.  Validate it locally and then run the same thing in the workflow.

Comment: yeah, if I run the script on the container, everything works fine, the database is working with the application. But when I use it on gitlab runner, the tomcat does not work properly.

Comment: Try to stop tomcat before running the app